# How can I track time from the command-line?

Tags: command-line, scripts

I am looking for a command to track the time.

I imagine the following workflow:

1. Run the command
2. ...do something else...
3. Return to the terminal window and stop the command
4. As an output you receive the time elapsed between 3 and 1

Comment: @JacobVlijm I really like the clarity of Anwar's reply below. As a non-technical user it's more easy to comprehend that the answers in the possible duplicate thread. What do you think?

Comment: @JacobVlijm I don't think this is a duplicate. The OP here is asking for a stopwatch, the question there is asking how to measure process execution time.

Comment: @Seth ok, vote retracted.

Comment: @Eric did you read my comment above?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/895659/134448) suggests to use

```
time cat
```

and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> to see the time.

You can also use

```
time read
```

and use <kbd>Enter</kbd> key

Also check [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/611582/134448) on the same question

Comment: This appears on the XKCD linux cheat sheet http://store-xkcd-com.myshopify.com/products/linux-cheat-shirt

Comment: nit: end the `cat` with `^D` instead of `^C` to exit with 0 instead of 130.

Answer (score 6):

How about:

```bash
stopwatch() { 
    local start=$SECONDS
    read -p "Hit Enter..."
    echo $((SECONDS-start)) seconds elapsed
}
```

In action:

```bash
$ stopwatch 
Hit Enter...
14 seconds elapsed
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple way of doing it is to take start time, and once you stop the script - take stop time. Finally, print the time difference. This can easily be done with Python:

```
python -c $'import time;start=time.time();\ntry:\n\twhile True: time.sleep(0.25)\nexcept: print(time.time()-start)'
```

Or long version for readability:

```python
import time
start=time.time();
try:
    while True: time.sleep(0.25)
except: 
    print(time.time()-start)
```

Stopping is done with Ctrl+C

Comment: `while True: pass` runs the CPU at 100%.  I'd suggest `while True: time.sleep(1e9)` instead (`signal.pause()` works too but requires an additional import).

Comment: @2012rcampion good point, edited that in already.

Comment: It is usually considered bad practice to catch _all_ exceptions (though in this case it's probably not too relevant), `except KeyboardInterrupt` would be better

Comment: @TobiasKienzler I'm aware of that. If this is a large project, i do split stuff to catch multiple exceptions. Feel free to look at my other code, indicators and such.  But in this case there is just one, so it's not exactly relevant. Plus, this is a quick and dirty way. Why nit golf it slightly ?

Comment: I fully agree, just thought it worth mentioning ;)